# mousepressed event is fired twice in java swing

Tags: java, swing

```
public class PDFParser implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

    static PDFParser p1 = new PDFParser();
    public static void main(Sring ar[])
    {
                ...........
                panel.addMouseListener(p1);
     }


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        System.out.println(e.getX() + "\t" + e.getY());
}


}
```

Comment: One possible reason is you've registered the listener more then once...

Comment: thanks for replying. but i have checked my code many times. i have registered only once. i have also rechecked it by adding comments in that statement and after that, event is not even fired once. so there might be some other issue.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses